# which msi database contains the product type details?

Tags: .net, windows, installation

can anybody tell which msi database table shall I use to change the application type or product type property of msi Package. also let me know how do it. basically I have an msi package and I want to change the type of this msi to mixed(Win32 and .NET). In Wise for windows installer and other tools its easy to do. we just need to change the product details tab in project summary section. but I am not able to figure out which table is being edited by this? thanks in advance for answering.

Answer (score 0):

For editing MSI files use ORCA - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370557(v=vs.85).aspx

For product type see MSDN help - MsiAssembly and MsiAssemblyName.